# How is ESC[2J and CLS different programmatically, and how would I use the Windows API to implement it in C?

Tags: c, windows, windows-console, ansi-escape

With Windows 10 now supporting VT100 escape sequences, I've noticed that the sequence ESC[2J and CLS are functionally the same, but CLS flickers quite a bit while ESC[2J does not. Here's 2 batch files as a simple example:

For ESC[2J

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A in ('ECHO prompt $E^| cmd') DO SET "ESC=%%A"
FOR /L %%Q in () DO (
    ECHO %ESC%[2J%ESC%[1;1HHi
)
```

For CLS

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A in ('ECHO prompt $E^| cmd') DO SET "ESC=%%A"
FOR /L %%Q in () DO (
    CLS
    ECHO %ESC%[1;1HHi
)
```

The CLS one flickers significantly more. Why is that? Is there a difference in how they are implemented functionally? The reason I am asking is because I'm using the Windows Console API in C to create a small game. I'm using this function to clear the text each loop:

```
void clearScreen(HANDLE handle, enum ClearType type) {
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(handle, &csbi)) {
        printf("Unable to read Console Buffer Info!");
        exit(0);
    }
    DWORD charwritten;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(handle, ' ', csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y, (COORD) {0, 0}, &charwritten);
}
```

But in a loop the result is the same as using CLS : lots of flicker. My question is, is there another way to clear the screen similar to ESC[2J (without flicker)? What other console function can I use?

Thanks in advance,

LardPies

Comment: In the batch files, I expect the difference is due to the fact that CLS followed by ECHO requires two different commands to be parsed and executed. You could test that theory by splitting the ECHO in the first batch file into two lines, i.e. `ECHO %ESC%[2J` followed by `ECHO %ESC%[1;1HHi`

Comment: @user3386109 Wow, you're right. But even so, how would I do the same in C using console APIs? As in the same effect as the first batch file?

Comment: I would create a string like `char clearMessage[] = { 27, '[', '2', 'J', 27, '[', '1', ';', '1', 'H', '\0' };`. Then create a large buffer, e.g. `char buffer[1000]`. Use `strcpy` to copy the string into the buffer, and `strcat` any text you want to the end of that string. Then it's just a matter of writing the string to the console.

Comment: @user3386109 That's what I thought initially, but then if I tried to have multiple colours. So I have to put SetConsoleAttributes in between each character. Is there a better way to this? THanks